# Why can I not instantiate a const instance of a class when non-const virtual methods are missing?

Tags: c++, constants, virtual

Why is this not legal?

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual void bar() = 0;
    virtual void barc() const = 0;
};

class Derived: public Base {
public:
    // deliberately omitted
    // virtual void bar()
    virtual void barc() const override { };
};

int main() {
    const Derived b;
    b.barc();
    // b.bar();
    // fails as expected with "passing 'const Bar' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers"
}
```

This fails with the following error, because I did not define `virtual void bar()`:

```
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:16:12: error: cannot declare variable 'd' to be of abstract type 'Derived'
  const Derived d;
            ^
prog.cpp:10:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within 'Derived':
 class Derived : public Base{
       ^
prog.cpp:6:15: note:    virtual void Base::bar()
  virtual void bar() = 0;
```

But I can't invoke `bar` here anyway, because that method is not marked const. If `bar` were defined, would there any legal way to invoke `d.bar()` indirectly anyway?

- Is using a `const_cast` allowed?
- Can I get in trouble with casting a super/subclass?

If not, then why must I define it?

Comment: Do what the compiler error tells you.  You need to define `bar()`

Comment: @NathanOliver. While you are obviously correct, I don't think that that's what OP is asking.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I don't want to define `bar()`. I want it to be illegal to declare a non-const `Bar`

Comment: @Eric. If you want it to be illegal to define non-const `Bar`, then why are you adding a non-const `bar`?

Comment: Ah.  I see where you are coming from now.  Basically why is it a compiler error to not define a function in which calling it would be a compiler error.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: I want `const Derived` to subclass `const Base`. The `bar` method is only part of the interface to a non-const `Base`. (I've renamed the classes to avoid confusion)

Comment: @NathanOliver: Bingo

Comment: @Eric. How do you expect D to access the non-const portions of B if you don't want there to be any?

Comment: @MadPhysicist: Which portions?

Comment: I was thinking of `bar`, but I suppose you can have an all-const `B` that requires a definition of non-const `bar` in the derived class anyway. Perhaps add another layer of inheritance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think there are a few blunt ways to put this:

1. Because there is only one vtable. The const and non-const objects share it.
2. Because you might `const_cast` the const object to a non-const one.
3. Because while the object is being constructed, it's not const.
4. Because constness is not a property of the object itself, it's a property attached to an object or reference that limits access to parts of the object.

The further questions were:

> Is using a const_cast allowed?

Yes. But what you do with the const_casted reference can quickly lead to "undefined behaviour". This does not mean "the world may end", as some would have you believe. What it means is, "the c++ standard does not define this behaviour - if the compiler, the hardware or the OS wish to, that's up to them". i.e. whatever you do with that const_casted reference is unlikely to be portable.

> Can I get in trouble with casting a super/subclass?

Casts are an open invitation for trouble.

Comment: Is it allowable (from a defined-behaviour standpoint) to const-cast away constness with `const_cast<Derived&>(d);`? I thought that was only allowed if the underlying object is non-const.

Comment: @Eric no, but it is not required for compiler to track where it is allowed to cast away constness, and where it is not, because, in general, it is simply not possible. So answer is "compiler should always expect that someone will try to do that"

Comment: @Eric yes... but: "*Modifying* a const object through a non-const access path and referring to a volatile object through a non-volatile glvalue results in undefined behavior."

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot: Right, but if the cast is undefined, then there's no reason that invoking `bar()` on the result shouldn't also be

Comment: @Eric the cast isn't undefined. The act of mutating a const object is. However, undefined does not mean "absolutely forbidden". It simply means that the standard does not define it. There is nothing stopping the implementation or the hardware from doing so.

Comment: @RichardHodges: Can't invoking a non-const method be construed as mutation? Or is mutation the act of actually changing fields?

Comment: @Eric I would have said the latter, either directly or as a result of a side-effect. Imagine that const object resides in one of a read-only memory page, ROM, or a read-write memory page. What's the result of writing? Depends. One will be exception, one will be nothing, the other will be a mutation (which may be missed because another const method assumed it could not happen).

Comment: Point 3 seems to be the biggest issue here - while [const constructors have been proposed in the past](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/1995/N0798.htm), it doesn't seem that ever made it into production

Comment: @Eric: _"Can't invoking a non-const method be construed as mutation? Or is mutation the act of actually changing fields?"_ That's a pretty good question in its own right. I'm fairly certain it involves invoking non-const functions on data members. Fairly. What if your hypothetical `const` member function only modifies `mutable` data members?

Answer (score 6):

You cannot instantiate an abstract class. End of story.

Comment: Only the end of the story if you consider this to be abstract. My question is why a class, where the only missing methods are the ones that can't be invoked under defined-behaviour, is still considered abstract.

Comment: _"Only the end of the story if you consider this to be abstract."_ But it is. That's just the way it is. Could C++ have been designed so that this edge case where allowed? Maybe. Would it have been useful? Doubtful. Would it have over-complicated lots of other things? Certainly.